# Can my question be moved to CrossValidated please?

Tags: support, migration

Can [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648526/diagnosing-why-r-is-crashing) be moved to CrossValidated please? I have flagged the question on SO and asked it to be moved here.

Reason: the package author is active on CV but not SO. He has kindly given some advice about this issue in [comments another question by me on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49068/why-does-mice-fail-for-one-dataset-and-not-the-other) but I fear if I post a new question on CV it might be closed as a duplicate/cross post.

Answer (score 3):

No offence, but the only valid reason for migration is when one question is off-topic on source SE and on-topic on the target SE.

If you want to reach package author directly, it is a better idea to send an e-mail than to chase him across SE network with off-topic posts.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying, but I don't think it's completely off-topic here as it may be a statistical problem to do with the data itself rather than a programming problem. I have tried emailing him before, but didn't get any response. He seems happy to comment on the problem in the comments on the unrelated question on CV. Is it a crazy idea to migrate it here and hope to get his input and later migrate it back to SO if it turns out to be a programming problem ? ;)

Comment: Robert, it all depends on what the question is. The one you reference very clearly is off topic here and on topic at SE, because it asks for `R` techniques to diagnose a crash. If you do have evidence that this is data-related and can introduce additional information about exactly how the data might be causing such a problem, you might be able to put the question in a statistical manner, which would make it on-topic here.

Comment: @whuber I do have evidence that it is data related in the sense that it crashes with certain subsets of the data and not with others (I think I mentioned that in the post) and I am working on generating small enough anonymised datasets that can be posted [related question: is there a recommended way to host data which is too big to use dput() ?].  Also, I wasn't specifically asking for R techniques to diagnose the crash - just generally "how can I diagnose the problem".

Comment: In this case it is difficult to separate the `R` programming issues with diagnosis from any statistical issues. What statistical techniques of diagnosis might you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber possibly issues to do with small cluster sizes and/or specifying the predictor matrix (off the top of my head) but I was hoping Steph van Buuren would be able to weigh in. To be honest it doesn't seem to be a problem with R programming because it runs fine with exactly the same code (and data structure) on other subsets of the data.

Comment: I see you're getting somewhere interesting, but how are we supposed to help with this if you don't make these concerns explicit in your question and unless you provide sample data?

Comment: @whuber I am going to attempt to provide sample data shortly in a major edit to the question. The problem is that it's far to big to use `dput()` - is it OK to host it externaly ? I fear that if I cut it down so far that I can use `dput()` (that is assuming it still crashes on such a small dataset) it won't be representative of the actual data. I have now managed to obtain a small-ish sample (~2800 obs on 17 vars) which still crashes and I just need to completely anonymise/jitter it.

Comment: Yes, hosting externally is a good idea.

Comment: @whuber OK - done... hope it's an improvement...